# Spring Data JPA SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601 with native query

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with native query in Spring Data JPA that works correctly in sql client

Failed query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a.id AS id, " +
        "a.key_1 AS key1, " +
        "a.key_2 AS key2, " +
        "a.total AS total, " +
        "a.modify_date AS modifyDate, " +
        "(SELECT COUNT(x.key_1) FROM book x WHERE x.key_1 = a.key_1) AS bookByKey1 " +
        "FROM book a", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<ResultDto> findAllByBookByKey1();
```

error says

> SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601 
> ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After separate subquery to new method it works as expected, I think this is a bug of Spring Data JPA